# SharePoint Designer 2007 - Workflow step with multiple if conditions

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2007

I've got a SharePoint list with multiple fields for names - they don't all need to contain names.

I want to set up a workflow to have:

if name1 is not empty { do this } 
if name2 is not empty { do this } 
if name3 is not empty { do this }

However all I've been able to find is an option to add extra 'else if' conditions, not 'if'.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add multiple Workflow Steps (right side of the Workflow Designer).

[image]

They are independent and will execute one after another.

It would look something like this:

**Step 1:**

*Conditions:* If `name1` is `not empty`
*Actions:* *{`do this`}*

**Step 2:**

*Conditions:* If `name2` is `not empty` 
*Actions:* *{`do this`}*

...